# Xcode project templates with schemes

Tags: ios, xcode, templates

I would like to create a project template for Xcode 9 which have predefined schemes and build configurations?

I would like to have a template with the following schemes and corresponding build configurations:

- "Dev" scheme with "Dev Debug" & "Dev Release" build configuration
- "Integration" scheme with "Integration Debug" & "Integration Release" build configuration
- "Production" scheme with "Production Debug" & "Production Release" build configuration

Is something like this possible? Anyone has had success with this? There is a good article about creating Xcode templates, but It does not describe how to create templates with predefined schemes: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-create-custom-project-templates-in-xcode-7

Any help would be appreciated, Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify next key in template:

```
<key>Targets</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Dev</string>
        <key>Configurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Debug</key>
            <dict/>
            <key>Release</key>
            <dict/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Integration</string>
        <key>Configurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Debug</key>
            <dict/>
            <key>Release</key>
            <dict/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Production</string>
        <key>Configurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Debug</key>
            <dict/>
            <key>Release</key>
            <dict/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Refer to [this](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/xcode4-template-documentation) documentation for further details.

Comment: thx for your answer. But This creates me 3 targets. What I would like to have is 1 target, 3 schemes with each 2 build configurations (Debug, Release)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you create different schemes and have separate config files ,

Got to your xcode -> your Project -> info tab as shown in the below screenshot

[image]

Click on the plus button as shown in the image you would get a pop up asking

[image]

select Duplicate Debug Configuration and name yours as Staging.

Now go to your "TARGETS" -> Select your App (DemoApp) -> BuildSettings
click on the small plus icon on top rightish corner as below

[image]

and click "ADD USER-DEFINED Setting"

Here you can define your custom different variables that you may need to differ 
eg: BASE_URL like below

[image]

Now you can just create a new Scheme "Staging" and use the configuration in the Run -> Info -> Build Configuration as shown below

[image]

In a similar manner you can have the different schemes and different configuration files that you need.

Comment: Thx for the answer Geet :) I know how to create Xcode schemes and build configs form within Xcode like you described. But what I would like to have, is a project template (something like the Single View Application template when starting a new project) which generates the schemes and configurations when starting a new project. You know what I mean?

Comment: There is no in-built template in xcode as far as I know, we need to create the schemes and configs acc to our requirement.

Comment: Yes, there is no built-in template in Xcode for this. That is why I would like to create one myself ;)